# Button help c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a button on a widows form that isn't working. the form is called **form2**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.setPlayerNames(p1.Text, p2.Text);
        this.Close();

    }
```

the code seems to check two TextBoxes, and assigns them a value in the next form, **form1** which is supposed to be linked. for some reason the link doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by " form1 which is supposed to be linked."?

Comment: Do you see an error?

Comment: form4 links to form2 and form3. Then form2 is supposed to link to form1

Comment: can you tell me what load information is supposed to be in each form?

Comment: seems like `form1` has 2 textboxes and `form2` also has 2 textboxes. On `form2` button click, you want to set the text of the textboxes in `form1`. Correct?

Comment: form2 has two textBoxes not form1. I just want the button on form2 to link to form1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, before you open the the form2 , set the global variable which is

```
public string textbox1Value = "";
public string textbox2Value = "";
```

Then open the the form2 something like form2.ShowDialog();

when calling button function, do this...

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1Value = p1.Text;
        textbox2Value = p2.Text;
        this.Close();

    }
```

After close the form2, below the form2.ShowDialog();
put this,

```
Form1.setPlayerNames(form2.textbox1Value, form2.textbox2Value );
```

Try.

And i realize one thing is, Form1 is appeared as light blue color, are you trying to call the class function inside the form1? Without declare the variable?

Comment: where do i put the global variables

Comment: global variable should put into form2

Comment: for eg for u,

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public string textbox1Value = "";
       public string textbox2Value = "";
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

ater working it a while I seemed to figure it out. This is what I had
on form2:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.setPlayerNames(p1.Text, p2.Text);
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        this.Close();
        f1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

on form1 i had this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = player1;
        label3.Text = player2;

    }
```